# how does tensorflow.data.Dataset repeat(count=None) method work

Tags: tensorflow

Tensorflow `data.Dataset` has a method `repeat(count=None)`(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#repeat), which repeats this dataset so each original value is seen `count` times. If count is set to `None` (by default), the dataset is to be repeated indefinitely. My question is, in the extreme case, how is the dataset of infinite size is handled 
 and stored in memory? When I try checking its contents using `as_numpy_iterator()`, the system will get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data.Dataset` is not a simple repetition of your data based on the `repeat(count=X)` method. It returns a python iterable, generating an iterator object.

> An iterator is an object that implements next, which is expected to return the next element of the iterable object that returned it, and raise a StopIteration exception when no more elements are available.
>   [Source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator)

Having a `Dataset` with "infinite repetitions" will load "indefinitely" a number of samples equal to your batch size. So, generally speaking, what you store in memory is one batch of samples. Moreover, shuffling with a buffer with a size greater than your dataset will help you having a representative batch based on the distribution of the elements in your actual dataset.